# Why should $\langle xf_r\rangle=0$ but $\langle\dot{x}f_r\rangle\ne 0$?

Tags: kinematics, brownian-motion, fluctuation-dissipation

All the $\langle\rangle$ in this question is the mean value theorem over a large number of experiments.

Consider a [Brownian particle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_motion) moving in a liquid with the viscosity $\mu$. The equation of motion in the $x$ axis is:

$$m\frac{d^2x}{dt^2}=-\mu\frac{dx}{dt}+f_r$$

where $f_r$ is a random force representing the collision with the small moleculars in the liquid.

Multiply the equation by $x$ we have

$$m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)-m\dot{x}^2=-\mu\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)+xf_r$$

Taking the mean value and if we assume that: $(1)$ $\langle xf_r\rangle=0$ and $(2)$ $\langle\frac{m\dot{x}^2}{2}\rangle=\frac{kT}{2}$ we got:

$$m\frac{d^2}{dt^2}\langle x^2\rangle=-\mu\frac{d}{dt}\langle x^2\rangle+\frac{2kT}{\mu}$$

This is a simple equation for $\langle x^2\rangle$ and when $t$ is larege enough we have $\langle x^2\rangle=\frac{2kT}{\mu}t$.

If we multiply the equation of motion by $\dot{x}$ and take the mean value, we will see that $\langle\dot{x}f_r\rangle\ne 0$. In fact this is the mean work per time done by the random force to win the viscous force.

How can I explain intuitively and simply why $\langle xf_r\rangle=0$ but $\langle\dot{x}f_r\rangle\ne 0$? The random force seem to not be related to $x$ or $\dot{x}$...

Answer (score 3):

Here is the intuitive explanation:

When a particle is moving, it will "run into" things. Thus, the "random force" from impacting another particle is not completely random: it is *in part correlated to the motion of the particle before the collision* - the force of the impact is more likely to be in a direction opposite to the current motion than any other direction. And it is this partial correlation which means that the expectation of $\langle \dot{x}f_r\rangle$ will not be zero.

On the other hand, there is *no* correlation between the current *position* of the particle and the direction of the force of the next impact - which is why tjhe expectation of $\langle x f_r\rangle$ *is* zero.

Comment: The force opposed to the motion is the total force I think. The random force has nothing to do with the velocity...

Comment: The motion that follows the random force has a component aligned with that force.

Comment: Then using the same argument there may be something correlated between $x$ and $f_r$. Why the correlation suddenly disappear from $\dot{x}$ to $x$?

Comment: When I am moving in a certain direction I am more likely to be hit from the front than the back... Because my own momentum plays a role in the impact. Thus the "random" force has a non-random component, correlated to my velocity.

Comment: If hited from the front, the force should be opposite to the velocity, so $\langle\dot{x}f_r\rangle$ should be negative, while in fact you can calculate and see that $\langle\dot{x}f_r\rangle$ in this case is positive

Answer (score 1):

In brownian motion (using the [langevin equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Langevin_equation)) the average (net) displacement is zero $\langle x\rangle=0$ and since the random force $f_r$ (usually white noise) is uncorrelated to the displacement (and has zero mean as well) the joint average $\langle xf_r\rangle=0$ is zero as well.

The correlation of the velocity (frictional viscocity term depending on velocity) and the random force is described in the [fluctuation-dissipation theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem#Brownian_motion) as such ([reference](http://www.cmu.edu/biolphys/deserno/pdf/FD.pdf)):

The random force (the *fluctuation*) is the **source and driving force** of the brownian particle, thus is **also the source** of the *secondary term of the friction* (friction, depending on velocity, the *dissipation*), thus these two terms **must be correlated**.

The expression $\langle\dot{x}f_r\rangle\ne 0$ defines exactly this correlation between these **two facets of the same effect** (*fluctuation-dissipation*).